# How to delete some specific data from the html page?

Tags: html

[image: This data I want to delete]

Here is my code:

```
{% extends 'app.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <div>
        <div class="alert alert-info">Transaction / Returning</div>

        <table id="table" class="table table-stripped">
            <thead class="alert-success">
            <tr>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Book Title</th>
                <th>Book Author</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Date Returned</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for borrow in borrows %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ borrow.student.all.0.firstname }} {{ borrow.student.all.0.lastname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ borrow.book.all.0.title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ borrow.book.all.0.author }}</td>
                    <td>{{ borrow.status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ borrow.date | date }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% if borrow.status == "Returned" %}
                            <button disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" href="#">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Returned
                            </button>
                        {% else %}
                            <form method="POST" action="">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="borrow_id" value="{{ borrow.id }}"/>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span> Return
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And yes, I want all the table should remain same but entries in the *Status, Date returned, Action* should be cleared.
It looks dirty in my project, so help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must delete their data in your database in order to clear those entries.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you can define a new function in your **views.py** file which will delete a particular entry from your database leaving everything same as it is.

And to access that function put a button in your html file.

That's it.

I hope it will help you!!